# Where Can I find some good examples in c++ to study object oriented concepts?

Tags: c++, oop, c++-concepts

I am trying to learn object oriented concepts by studying a real world example in c++.
This exmple should illustrate all concepts like inheritance, encapsulation, overloading, polymorphism etc.

Comment: The question was closed before I could post the answer but I'd first recommend C++ FAQ, which provides a great overview of OOP in C++. As far as projects go, some highly regarded code bases include: Qt, Chromium and Ogre 3D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering a [quite popular post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) , there are lot of solutions to your problem, probably the best one is [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545).

I would like to also recommend another path: pick 1 between Obj-C and Java if you can deviate a little from the original focus.

The reason why I'm suggesting this is the long time existence of Java, combined with its big popularity in both production and education, and the fact that Obj-C is somehow an object oriented language that "exposed" itself in the way this mechanisms works, there are a lot of pointers and really simple but powerful concepts that can help you understand this.

It's also possible to use Obj-C on platforms that are not MAC OS driven but you should use `clang`, not `gcc`, `gcc` is a little bit `behind` on objc support, at least this is what I experienced.

There is also the usual [list of free resources](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md) with a lot of goodies that always helps .